# Select multiple files on a C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I am moving from .net asp.net to C# winform.

I want to select multiple files on a C# winform then show the selected files on the screen that user can remove them...

Which control should I use for showing the items on screen winform?

Comment: @Tigran Probably because it showed little research effort. (Note: I did not down vote it)

Comment: @devn, change your title please, the fact that you're coming from ASP.NET isn't relevant

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should use Listbox. The user can easily select multiple items in a listbox using the typical Windows Ctrl/Shift keys and clicking on the items they want to select.

Answer (score 0):

Question is too generic.

Just a couple of options:

[ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx)

[ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwb14tw.aspx)

Depends on what is that *Item* you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a screenshot and code snippet from a custom control. This should give you a starting point for creating your own.

[image: The File Selector GUI]

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve a list of available files in the input directory
    /// </summary>
    private void LoadAvaliableFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            this.lv_AvailableFiles.Items.Clear();

            //Pick up files from structure
            //Firstly pick up all files in the target directory
            string[] filesFound = this.m_watcher.GetFiles();

            // Verify that we have some files to display in the list
            if (filesFound != null && filesFound.Length > 0)
            {
                // The ArrayList will contain PreConversionData objects
                foreach (string filePath in filesFound)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

                    //create a list view item for the file
                    ListViewItem newFile = new ListViewItem(fileName);
                    newFile.Text = fileName;
                    newFile.ToolTipText = filePath;
                    newFile.Tag = filePath;

                    // Add the new item to the list
                    this.lv_AvailableFiles.Items.Add(newFile);
                }
            }

            this.lv_AvailableFiles.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.WriteLine( Category.Warning, "Exception detected populating the available files list", ex);
        }

    }
```

My code is using a folder watcher to catch any newly added files but you could just as easily use

```
string [] filesFound = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
```